# Produce a Linear Cut List for Woodworking

Tags: vba, excel

I was inspired to write this by a recent review of [cutting pipes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154115/spreadsheet-to-calculate-how-to-cut-pipes).

The only thing I'm really iffy about is using the `WriteCuts` method. I couldn't figure out a way to `Let listOfCuts()` out of `Class TwoByFour`.

#### Example

If you want to build a table (***out of 2x4s***), you'll need

- 4 legs of x length
- 2 long sides of y length and
- 2 short sides of z length

[image]

This could be represented in a table like so -

```
Length  Qty
48      4
30      2
15      2
```

Assuming length is in imperial inches and I can only buy 96" boards at the store, I want to know how many boards I need to buy to get the lengths and quantities I want. In this (theoretical) case I need to buy 3 boards -

```
Board   Cuts        Remainder
1       48, 48         0
2       48, 30, 15     3
3       48, 30, 15     3
```

[image]

---

#### Algorithm

So with this simplified explanation, I can figure out my cuts by using the board's off-cut piece for each length until I need a new board. This is the algorithm I'm using.

---

#### Pseudocode -

1. Put length/qty table in array
2. Create list of pieces (descending in length)
3. Use a board until you can't make another piece
4. Get another board
5. Repeat until all pieces are cut

---

#### Class TwoByFour

```
Option Explicit
    Const BOARD_LENGTH As Long = 96
    Private index As Long
    Private remainder As Double
    Private listOfCuts() As Double
    
    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        ReDim listOfCuts(1 To 1)
        listOfCuts(1) = BOARD_LENGTH
    End Sub
    
    Public Property Get NumberOfCuts() As Long
        NumberOfCuts = UBound(listOfCuts)
    End Property
    
    Public Property Get Offcut() As Double
        Offcut = listOfCuts(UBound(listOfCuts))
    End Property
    
    Public Sub MakeCut(length As Double)
        index = UBound(listOfCuts)
        remainder = listOfCuts(index) - length
        listOfCuts(index) = length
        ReDim Preserve listOfCuts(1 To index + 1)
        listOfCuts(index + 1) = remainder
    End Sub
    
    Public Function WriteCuts() As Variant
        WriteCuts = listOfCuts
    End Function
```

---

#### Code

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DimensionalLumberCutList()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim listOfComponents() As Double
    listOfComponents = GetListOfComponents(lastRow)
    
    Dim lumberStack As Collection
    Set lumberStack = New Collection
    Dim board As TwoByFour
    Dim boardCount As Long
    Dim index As Long
    

    Do
        Set board = New TwoByFour
        For index = LBound(listOfComponents) To UBound(listOfComponents)
            If board.Offcut < listOfComponents(UBound(listOfComponents)) Then
                lumberStack.Add board
                Exit For
            End If
            If board.Offcut > listOfComponents(index) And listOfComponents(index) <> 0 Then
                board.MakeCut listOfComponents(index)
                listOfComponents(index) = 0
            End If
            If index = UBound(listOfComponents) Then
                lumberStack.Add board
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Loop While Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(listOfComponents) > 0

    
    With Sheet2
        .UsedRange.Clear
        For index = 1 To lumberStack.Count
            .Range(.Cells(index, 1), .Cells(index, lumberStack(index).NumberOfCuts)) = lumberStack(index).WriteCuts
        Next
    End With

End Sub


Private Function GetListOfComponents(ByVal lastRow As Long) As Double()
    Dim componentDataArray As Variant
    componentDataArray = PopulateComponentDataArray(lastRow)
    Dim numberOfComponents As Long
    numberOfComponents = GetNumberOfComponents(componentDataArray)
    Dim componentDoubleArray() As Double
    ReDim componentDoubleArray(1 To numberOfComponents)
    Dim index As Long
    index = 1
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim quantityOfEach As Long
    For counter = 1 To lastRow - 1
        For quantityOfEach = 1 To componentDataArray(counter, 2)
            componentDoubleArray(index) = componentDataArray(counter, 1)
            index = index + 1
        Next
    Next
    CombSortNumbers componentDoubleArray
    GetListOfComponents = componentDoubleArray
End Function

Private Function PopulateComponentDataArray(ByVal lastRow As Long) As Variant
    Dim componentRange As Range
    Set componentRange = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(2, 1), Sheet1.Cells(lastRow, 2))
    PopulateComponentDataArray = componentRange
End Function

Private Function GetNumberOfComponents(ByVal componentDataArray As Variant) As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = LBound(componentDataArray) To UBound(componentDataArray)
        GetNumberOfComponents = GetNumberOfComponents + componentDataArray(counter, 2)
    Next
End Function

Private Function GetTotalLength(ByVal listOfComponents As Variant) As Double
    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(listOfComponents) To UBound(listOfComponents)
        GetTotalLength = GetTotalLength + listOfComponents(index)
    Next
End Function
```

---

#### Combsort

I'm utilizing a previous piece of code [that's been reviewed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145862/comb-sort-in-vba) to sort the array descending, but here it is anyway -

```
Private Sub CombSortNumbers(ByRef numberArray() As Double, Optional ByVal sortAscending As Boolean = False)
    Const SHRINK As Double = 1.3
    Dim initialSize As Long
    initialSize = UBound(numberArray())
    Dim gap As Long
    gap = initialSize
    Dim index As Long
    Dim isSorted As Boolean

    Do While gap > 1 And Not isSorted
        gap = Int(gap / SHRINK)
        If gap > 1 Then
            isSorted = False
        Else
            gap = 1
            isSorted = True
        End If
        index = LBound(numberArray)
        Do While index + gap <= initialSize
            If sortAscending Then
                If numberArray(index) > numberArray(index + gap) Then
                    SwapElements numberArray, index, index + gap
                    isSorted = False
                End If
            Else
                If numberArray(index) < numberArray(index + gap) Then
                    SwapElements numberArray, index, index + gap
                    isSorted = False
                End If
            End If
            index = index + 1
        Loop
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub SwapElements(ByRef numberArray() As Double, ByVal i As Long, ByVal j As Long)
    Dim temporaryHolder As Double
    temporaryHolder = numberArray(i)
    numberArray(i) = numberArray(j)
    numberArray(j) = temporaryHolder
End Sub
```

Comment: From a carpenter/framer's perspective, I wouldn't fix the length of the board at 96". I can buy 8', 10', 12' & 16' 2x dimensional lumber at my local lumber yard. Other than that, I'm going to steal this! :)

Comment: That's why windows roll down... :)

Comment: The problem is quite interesting, isn't it? Your code little more advanced than my code, but I will test it later and see if I can understand what is happening :)

Comment: Btw, how did you create the graphics for your problem?

Comment: Yeah, it looks a handy tool in visualize problems. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I approached the problem with some differences in the methods assigned to the `TwoByFour` class. One of the things I added is to add the blade kerf - the width of the material removed by the saw blade, because this reduces the amount of remaining material.

For the `TwoByFour` class, I believed the object could know about its original length, the amount of unused length remaining, and the number of cuts already made. Because I always want to know which component is getting cut from which board, I chose to create an `ID` for each component piece in order to keep track of them.

**Class `TwoByFour`:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type BoardInfo
    boardLength As Double
    kerfWidth As Double
    unusedLength As Double
    cutPieces As Scripting.Dictionary
End Type
Private this As BoardInfo

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    this.boardLength = 0
    this.kerfWidth = 0
    this.unusedLength = this.boardLength
    Set this.cutPieces = New Scripting.Dictionary 'stored as <ComponentID, length>
End Sub

Public Property Let StockLength(newLength As Double)
    '--- new length also resets the number of cuts
    this.boardLength = newLength
    this.unusedLength = this.boardLength
    Set this.cutPieces = New Scripting.Dictionary 'stored as <ComponentID, length>
End Property
Public Property Get StockLength() As Double
    StockLength = this.boardLength
End Property

Public Property Let BladeKerf(newKerf As Double)
    this.kerfWidth = newKerf
End Property
Public Property Get BladeKerf() As Double
    BladeKerf = this.kerfWidth
End Property

Public Property Get NumberOfCutPieces() As Long
    NumberOfCutPieces = this.cutPieces.Count
End Property

Public Property Get LeftoverLength() As Double
    LeftoverLength = this.unusedLength
End Property

Public Function MakeCut(cutLength As Double, id As String) As Double
    '--- returns the remaining board length or zero if the cut can't be made
    If (cutLength < (this.unusedLength + this.kerfWidth)) Or _
       (cutLength = this.unusedLength) Then
        this.cutPieces.Add id, cutLength
        this.unusedLength = this.unusedLength - cutLength - this.kerfWidth
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetPieceLength(index As Long) As Double
    '--- returns the length of the indicated piece
    If (index > 0) And (index <= NumberOfCutPieces) Then
        GetPieceLength = this.cutPieces.Items(index - 1)
    Else
        GetPieceLength = 0
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetPieceID(index As Long) As String
    '--- returns the length of the indicated piece
    If (index > 0) And (index <= NumberOfCutPieces) Then
        GetPieceID = this.cutPieces.Keys(index - 1)
    Else
        GetPieceID = "n/a"
    End If
End Function
```

I tend to organize data in Dictionaries or Arrays. In the main `Sub` I really used both. I agreed with @Raystafarian about sorting the components by size, but since I used a `Dictionary`, I wanted to use sorting functions "out of the box".

> The code below relies on the `SortDictionary` routine from Craig Pearson, as noted in the code. (Get it [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm).) In turn, the `SortDictionary` routine relies on the `QSort` module. (Get it [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx).) Both are required to make the sorting work properly.

The main routine `DimensionalLumberCutList` is based on values on the worksheet, arranged as:

[image]

So the main work is done in these methods:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub DimensionalLumberCutList()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim StockLength As Double
    Dim kerfWidth As Double
    StockLength = CDbl(ws.Range("StockLength"))
    kerfWidth = CDbl(ws.Range("KerfWidth"))

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim listOfComponents As Dictionary
    Set listOfComponents = New Dictionary
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '--- requires all lengths to be unique
    Dim length As Double
    Dim qty As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        length = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
        qty = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
        If qty > 0 Then
            For j = 1 To qty
                listOfComponents.Add (length & "-" & j), length
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    '--- from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionsAndDictionaries.htm
    ' sorted for the longest pieces appear first
    SortDictionary listOfComponents, False, True

    Dim finalBoardCuts() As TwoByFour
    finalBoardCuts = CutMyPieces(listOfComponents, StockLength, kerfWidth)

    '--- output the results
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim numBoards As Long
    Dim boardName As String
    Dim thisBoard As TwoByFour
    numBoards = UBound(finalBoardCuts)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Your project requires " & numBoards & " boards:"
        Debug.Print "(calculated with a " & kerfWidth & " inch blade kerf)"
        For i = 1 To numBoards
            boardName = "Board " & i & ": "
            Set thisBoard = finalBoardCuts(i)
            For j = 1 To thisBoard.NumberOfCutPieces
                Debug.Print boardName;
                Debug.Print "component " & thisBoard.GetPieceID(j);
                Debug.Print " at " & thisBoard.GetPieceLength(j) & " inches"
            Next j
        Next i
    Else
        Debug.Print "No boards to cut."
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CutMyPieces(ByRef compList As Dictionary, _
                             Optional boardLength As Double = 96#, _
                             Optional bladeWidth As Double = 0.125) As TwoByFour()
    '--- resulting dictionary returns list of <ComponentId, board number>
    Dim boards() As TwoByFour
    ReDim boards(1 To 1)
    Set boards(UBound(boards)) = New TwoByFour
    boards(UBound(boards)).StockLength = boardLength
    boards(UBound(boards)).BladeKerf = bladeWidth

    Dim componentLength As Double
    Dim componentId As Variant
    For Each componentId In compList.Keys
        componentLength = compList(componentId)
        If componentLength > boards(UBound(boards)).StockLength Then
            '--- too big for us, so skip it
            Debug.Print "Component " & CStr(componentId) & " is larger than the stock available."
        Else
            If componentLength <= boards(UBound(boards)).LeftoverLength Then
                boards(UBound(boards)).MakeCut componentLength, CStr(componentId)
            Else
                ReDim Preserve boards(1 To UBound(boards) + 1)
                Set boards(UBound(boards)) = New TwoByFour
                boards(UBound(boards)).StockLength = boardLength
                boards(UBound(boards)).BladeKerf = bladeWidth
                boards(UBound(boards)).MakeCut componentLength, CStr(componentId)
            End If
        End If
    Next componentId
    CutMyPieces = boards
End Function
```

I maybe cheated by writing the results to the debug window, but that can easily be changed. Not sure if this solves your problem or not.

But I believe the algorithm to allocate components to boards can certainly be improved, especially when you add in the blade kerf.

Here are my results from the data shown:

```
Your project requires 5 boards:
(calculated with a 0.125 inch blade kerf)
Board 1: component 48-3 at 48 inches
Board 2: component 48-4 at 48 inches
Board 3: component 48-1 at 48 inches
Board 4: component 48-2 at 48 inches
Board 4: component 30-2 at 30 inches
Board 5: component 30-1 at 30 inches
Board 5: component 15-2 at 15 inches
Board 5: component 15-1 at 15 inches
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm going to have to study that class module, it's definitely new to me

Comment: I had written another version including kerf while waiting for an answer here, but now I've adapted to using the dictionary within the class - you keeping the component ID available was a great idea.